# Ubuntu 23.04: Steam games won't start after installing Vulkan shaders

Tags: drivers, nvidia, games, steam, vulkan

I have had this problem with Crusader Kings 3, Victoria 3, and Stellaris on Steam. Every time the Vulkan Shaders finishes installing, it starts the game for a second and then it closes it. I press "start" again and it instantly closes the game again. I have using the Nvidia version 525 drivers and my GPU is a 3060ti. I have tried the older 470 Nvidia driver, but that did not work.